# Приклади речень сформованих з омонімів (антанаклаза)

Tags: омоніми

З Вікіпедії:

> [Антанакла́за](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0), антанакласис (*дав.-гр. ἀντανάκλασις ‘відбиття, луна; використання слова у зміненому значенні’*) — стилістична фігура, яка полягає в повторенні того самого слова у різних значеннях, або вживанні омонімів чи омонімічних форм різних слів.

Типовим прикладом в англійській мові є така фраза:

> «[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)» (*«Бізони з Буффало, налякані [іншими] бізонами з Буффало, залякують [інших] бізонів з Буффало»*)

Ця ж вікі-сторінка наводить і приклад українською:

> Косий з косою косою косою косою косив. (*«Косоокий з навскісною чуприною кривою косою косив»*.)

Чи є якісь інші приклади антанаклази в українській?

Answer (score 5):

[Звідси](http://dn.khnu.km.ua/dn/k_default.aspx?M=k0914&T=07_1&lng=1&st=0) (Станіславова Л. Л., Курс «Стилістика української мови», Хмельницький національний університет, 2014).

Ліна Костенко:

> вогонь **погас** — пішов **по гас**

...

> Я уздрів, побачив **сонце**!
>
> І здалося мені — **сон це**!

...

> день ясний, **а не мій**,
>
> від цензурного Літ’а,
>
> від міських **анемій**.

В. Сосюра:

> У морі **зір** мій **зір** в задумі тоне,
>
> Таємно з ними серце розмовля.

В. Еллан-Блакитний:

> Струни **настрою настрою**
>
> На бадьорий юний лад.

О. Ірванець:

> Усміхнися і йди і усмішку **з губи** не **згуби**.

Answer (score 5):

Багато прикладів мовних ігор можна знайти у дитячій літературі. Наприклад у книжці "Улюблені вірші" видавництва "Абабагаламага" є такі:

> У **стоніжок** по **сто ніжок**.
>   Всі **сто милися**, всі **стомилися**
>
> Кістку пес в зубах **тримав**
>   І в запасі ще **три мав**.
>
> На горі росте **квасоля**,
>   А згори несе **квас Оля**.

Автор цих трьох здається Ігор Січовик, ще 15 є на сторінці "[Дитячі каламбури](http://abetka.ukrlife.org/kalamburs.htm)".

Ще один вірш з тієї ж книжки написав Мойсей Фішбейн:

> Ките, ките, покатай!
>   Сяду верхи на **кита й**
>   Помандруємо в **Китай**!
>   Тільки я і тільки ти.
>   Що за диво ті кити!

Answer (score 4):

Зі щойно вигаданого:

- З трибуни стрибун стрибав стрибки.
- Складно склади складати ладно.

Загалом оцей ((с)к)лад настільки сильно навантажений в нашій мові, що, гадаю, з ним можна вигадати щось досить довге.

Comment: це прекрасно! :-)

Comment: +1, але, все-таки, «з» трибуни.